# USB-to-VGA adapter or HDMI-to-VGA adapter

Tags: usb, hdmi, vga, cable, adapter

I have to connect my laptop to a projector with VGA input port.

Would it be better if I get a USB-to-VGA adapter or should I get a HDMI-to-VGA adapter? Which would give me better quality and why? The latter is higher priced. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by better quality.  The quality will be limited by the resolution limitations of the projector when connected to a VGA in either case.

Comment: What is a USB-to-VGA adapter? You mean those USB display card with a VGA output?

Comment: I don't think HDMI-to-VGA is more expensive either: http://www.amazon.com/StarTech-com-HD2VGAE2-Converter-Desktop-Ultrabooks/dp/B00BUKO6CW/ http://www.amazon.com/Startech-USB32VGAES-External-Monitor-Adapter/dp/B00H91BRZU/

Comment: I bet that those USB display card can only provides very basic display capabilities and there could be issues with driver, video playback...

Comment: I imagine it depends on which adapter of either type that you buy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

USB-VGA is going to be much more unreliable in any situation since it requires a special adapter. USB traditionally isn't even used for Video and is strictly a Data connection.

I'd stick with HDMI-VGA. Even then, make sure you are aware that VGA will not carry audio and you will not have sound. You will need a separate 1/8" Phono cable (AUX cable) to carry the sound.

Other options, if your laptop has them, are DisplayPort or MiniDP/Thunderbolt to HDMI.

Comment: USB to VGA will also be relatively choppy, unless its USBv3.  Older verisons are fine for spreadsheets and browsing, but not video.